# Specify additional link directories for CMake's find_package() on linux

Tags: cmake, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to link a library (SFML) by using CMake's find_package() command. All works well if I put SFML's libraries directly into the /usr/local/lib folder, but as soon as I create a subfolder (for organizational purposes) I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake:355 (message):
  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY
  SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

I then tried to search for ways of specifying the new directory (which, by the way, is simply /usr/local/lib/SFML) to the find_package() function, but nothing I found seems to work.

#### CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
# initialize project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(Proj)

# compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# load packages
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)
find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS graphics window system)

# headers directories
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

# project directories
include_directories(headers)

# project sources
file(GLOB SRC src/*.cpp)

# create exectuables
add_executable(Proj ${SRC}) 

# link libraries
target_link_libraries(Proj ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DPENDENCIES})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of "Find" scripts, CMake doesn't support specifying additional library's subdirectories. But you may specify exact library directories via [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/local/lib/SFML")
find_package(SFML ...)
```

---

Actually, variable CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH affects on `find_library` calls, but most of "Find" scripts search libraries using this command.